# Solving equation $y^2-2\ln(y)=x^2$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x70hf.jpg)Can someone help me to solve this equation:
$$y^2-2\ln(y)=x^2$$
I want to find y.
I have tried to solve the problem but I couldn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show the steps what you have tried so far.

Comment: and, why do you want find $y$?

Comment: Just manipulate the equation and make use of the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: I didn't see option to add a photo, so I didn't post what I tried.

Comment: @Anthony there are couple problems with this, the workarounds of which depend on OP providing more details. Firstly, for negative outputs the branch of product log matters significantly. Second, no matter which real branch we choose, the given equation seems to have no real $y$ solutions, only purely imaginary ones.

Comment: Sorry Anthony can you please post a detailed answer. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: @Majdgh you can show your work by typesetting your equations. The tutorial is [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Give it your best attempt and we can fix any errors once you've tried.

Comment: But I could draw it for example using geogebra, that means it has a solution

Comment: I added a picture of what I have tried

Comment: I see your point! I guess it uses another branch. But you should edit your post with context, why do you need to solve this, have you tried typesetting? Images for work are frowned upon here, because if someone else needs help with a similar question, the search will not work on images.

Comment: @NinadMunshi plot the function $f(t)=t^2-2\log(t)$. The equation *does* have real solutions (one or two), provided $x^2$ is bigger than $\inf(f)$.

Comment: @Anthony you're absolutely right! It was a sign error on my part

Comment: @Majdgh Note that If $(a,b)\in f\implies (b,a)\in f^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming you only care about real solutions).

The Lambert ${W}$ function is the inverse to ${xe^{x}}$ (well, that depends on the value of $x$ - you will need to change the branch accordingly. If ${x\geq -1}$, we take the ${W_0}$ branch, otherwise - you take the ${W_{-1}}$ branch. For simplicity, for now I will refer to the whole thing as just ${W}$). That is,

$${W(xe^{x})=x}$$

Notice that your equation

$${y^2 - 2\ln(y)= x^2}$$

is equivalent to

$${2\ln(y) -y^2 = -x^2}$$

raising $e$ to both sides yields

$${e^{2\ln(y) - y^2}=e^{-x^2}=y^2e^{-y^2}}$$

Multiply both sides by ${-1}$ once again to get

$${\Rightarrow -y^2e^{-y^2}=-e^{-x^2}}$$

And now use Lambert ${W}$

$${W(-y^2e^{-y^2})=W(-e^{-x^2})=-y^2}$$

And so you get

$${y^2 = -W(-e^{-x^2})}$$

which implies that

$${y = \pm\sqrt{-W(-e^{-x^2})}}$$

But which branch of ${W}$ do you take? - it turns out in this context you need to take both one at a time, since both will give you valid solutions. Going back to

$${-y^2e^{-y^2}=-e^{-x^2}}$$

A quick cheap way of seeing this is that by looking at the graph of ${-y^2e^{-y^2}}$ you can see it has a range of ${\left[-\frac{1}{e},0\right]}$, and every value in it's range is hit by some $y$ such that ${(-y^2) < -1}$, and also get's hit by some ${y}$ such that ${(-y^2)\geq -1}$ also. And so if you take the ${W_0}$ branch - it'll give you the $y$ solution such that ${(-y^2)\geq -1}$, and if you take the ${W_{-1}}$ branch it'll give you the solution such that ${(-y^2) < -1}$. Both solutions are important.

In the context of real solutions, notice that the range of ${-y^2e^{-y^2}}$ being ${\left[-\frac{1}{e},0\right]}$ also forces our ${x}$ to be in the domain of ${(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,\infty)}$ (since this domain ensures the range of ${-e^{-x^2}}$ matches accordingly).

Comment: Nice solution! But you should mention the other two solutions you get since Lambert W has two possible outputs for negative solutions.

Comment: Correct, I was about to comment that $W$ has two branches ! You chose only one. $W$ is not a proper *function*, since $xe^x$ has no inverse (it isn't one-to-one on its whole domain !). I'm starting to wonder whether it's a good thing to use $W$. There's no way to properly compute it anyways, so a simple variation table for the function $f(t)=t^2-2\log(t)$ may suffice.

Comment: Really thanks for the solution, but should I put instead of W at the last line to get the value of y

Comment: For example if I want to calculate the Vale of y at x = 5 for example

Comment: @Majdgh $W$ is a special function, you have no regular expression for it other than $W$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose it's fine considering it as a multifunction, but 1) you called it a function and 2) this made you miss the *real* solutions. OP looks like he might only be interested in those, and may not be familiar to this concept.

Comment: @Majdgh There are many ways to compute W in practice. However, none of them give an exact value, hence why we just leave the answer in terms of the $W$ function. However, if you want to find *approximate* solutions, just type your original question into WolframAlpha. The only *integer* solutions to this equation are $x=\pm1$,$y=1$.

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose On the third to last line, you wrote $W(-e^{-x^2})=-y^2$, but on the second to last line, you wrote $y^2=-W(e^{-x^2})$. Assuming that the third to last line is correct, shouldn't it read $y^2=-W(-e^{-x^2})$?

Comment: @Anthony I forgot to edit the answer, just done it now

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Are you sure? Inside the bracket, it should read $-e^{-x^2}$, not $e^{-x^2}$. I'm talking about that line that follows from the comment 'and so you get'. Later on in your working, you seem to have wrote it correctly, so this did not change the final answer. Other than that, I think your answer is very good. +1

Comment: @Joe no you're right damnit hahaha! All those minus signs my eyes didn't pick up on the mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much @Riemann'sPointyNose for your help

Comment: @Majdgh no problem! Rearranging for $y$ in this question is definitely not easy as you can see, and involves a special function - but this is all that we can do :)

Comment: Yes you are right @Riemann'sPointyNose it's not easy, actually I have to study more advanced mathematics to understand it. Thanks